# Multi-threading with unsafe methods in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, parallel.foreach

I have a `Datatable` with millions of record, I have use `Parallel.Foreach` to get each record. With each record a method `AddAttendace` is called.

```
var AttCollection = from o in Employees
                    select o;

Parallel.ForEach(AttCollection, ac =>
{
   AddAttendace(_ep.Get_V(ac.Key, true, null), ac.Value);
});
```

And in `AddAttendace` methods other multiple methods called that use database conection to get data from database, I am using Entity Frame Work.

```
public bool AddAttendace(V_HR_EmployeePlacementDetailed emp, DateTime dt) 
{
  var empPos = _position.Get(emp.department_id, emp.position_id);
  var empPosRoster = _rosterPosition.Get(emp.department_id, emp.position_id, dt);

  var empPosLateArrival = empPos.late_arrival;
  var empPosEarlyDeparture = empPos.early_departure;

  if (empPosRoster != null)
    {
      empPosLateArrival = empPosRoster.late_arrival.HasValue ? empPosRoster.late_arrival.Value : empPosLateArrival;
      empPosEarlyDeparture = empPosRoster.early_departure.HasValue ? empPosRoster.early_departure.Value : empPosEarlyDeparture;
    }

  var empLeaves = _lapp.GetAll(null, null, dt, dt, null, true, null, null, null, null);

  var att = GetAll(dt, new List<long> { emp.employee_id });
  var obj = att.Count() > 0 ? att.First() : Get();
  var inRecords = _inOut.GetAll(obj.employee_attendance_id, true, null);
  var outRecords = _inOut.GetAll(obj.employee_attendance_id, null, true);

  obj.employee_id = emp.employee_id;
  obj.date = dt;
  obj.arrival_time = inRecords.Count() == 0 ? dt.TimeOfDay : obj.arrival_time;
  obj.departure_time = inRecords.Count() > 0 ? dt.TimeOfDay : obj.departure_time;

  dt.TimeOfDay - inRecords.First().@in.Value : obj.total_hours_worked;

  if (obj.arrival_time.HasValue && empPosLateArrival.HasValue && obj.arrival_time > empPosLateArrival)
      obj.late_arrival = obj.arrival_time - empPosLateArrival;
  if (obj.early_departure.HasValue && empPosEarlyDeparture.HasValue && obj.departure_time < empPosEarlyDeparture)
      obj.early_departure = empPosEarlyDeparture -  obj.departure_time;

      obj.present = true;
      obj.leave = false;
      obj.holiday = false;
      obj.department_id = emp.department_id;
      obj.position_id = emp.position_id;

      var lapp = (from o in empLeaves
                  where o.employee_id == emp.employee_id
                  select o).FirstOrDefault();

     if (lapp != null && obj.present != true){
        obj.leave = true;
        obj.leave_type_id = lapp.LeaveTypeId;
      }
     var v = _inOut.Get();
     if (att.Count() > 0){
         Update();
         v.attendance_id = obj.employee_attendance_id;
      }
     else{
          Insert(obj);
          v.attendance_id = GetCurrentIdent();
      }
      if (inRecords.Count() == 0){
          v.@in = dt.TimeOfDay;
          v.inout_type_id = 1;
       }
      else{
          v.@out = dt.TimeOfDay;
          v.inout_type_id = 2;
                }
          _inOut.Insert(v);

            return false;
          }
```

The `AddAttendace` took 2 seconds to complete execute and for `12000` record it takes so long time to execute, so thats why i have use Parallel.Foreach. But other multiple methods called inside the `AddAttendace` are thread unsafe, I have use `lock` statement in each method

```
public V_HR_EmployeePlacementDetailed Get_V(long employeeID, bool? IsActivePlacement, bool? IsActive)
 {
   lock (locker)
    {
      var result = from o in entity.V_HR_EmployeePlacementDetailed
                    where o.employee_id == employeeID
                    && ((IsActive.HasValue && o.IsActive == IsActive) 
                    || !IsActive.HasValue)
                    && ((IsActivePlacement.HasValue && o.IsActiveInPlacement == IsActivePlacement) 
                    || !IsActivePlacement.HasValue)
                    orderby o.employee_placement_id descending
                    select o;
      return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
 }
```

But still `AddAttendace` method takes 2 second to execute for each record, whats wrong with my code?
Should I use some other technique of multi-threading.

Comment: Do you have a separate context in each thread, because EF contexts are not thread safe...

Comment: no i do't have, but i have use lock statement for this reason that while one thread is using db conext other should b in queue.

Comment: Did you try attaching a profiler to it to see what is actually taking the time? The first question to ask is whether your code is Disk, CPU or Network bound. Multiple threads will only improve performance of CPU bound tasks. Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Comment: No there is no disk or network bounding

Comment: So if 90% of the time is spent querying the database, what do you feel you are going to gain out of the threading if you have a lock around the query. I agree with Martin above....if your bottleneck is in the query itself then no amount of multi-threading is going to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Really you need to profile this to get more information. Blindly throwing threads at a problem is likely to just lead to more trouble down the road. Visual Studio includes a profiler in the latest versions or you can use tools like Redgate's [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/?utm_source=bing&utm_term=%2Bc%23%20%2Bprofiler&utm_campaign=GS%20%7C%20Platform%20%7C%20C%23%20%7C%20BMM&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=DNizNv8r%7Cpcrid%7C6787401962%7Cpkw%7C%2Bc%23%20%2Bprofiler%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7C). If you can't figure that out you can simply stick time logging calls all throughout your code to narrow down the issue (see below). Only once you know which exact line is causing the issue is it worth optimizing.

```
    public bool AddAttendace(V_HR_EmployeePlacementDetailed emp, DateTime dt)
    {
        var stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var empPos = _position.Get(emp.department_id, emp.position_id);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("a {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        var empPosRoster = _rosterPosition.Get(emp.department_id, emp.position_id, dt);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("b {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        var empPosLateArrival = empPos.late_arrival;
        var empPosEarlyDeparture = empPos.early_departure;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("c {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        if (empPosRoster != null)
        {                
            empPosLateArrival = empPosRoster.late_arrival.HasValue ? empPosRoster.late_arrival.Value : empPosLateArrival;
            empPosEarlyDeparture = empPosRoster.early_departure.HasValue ? empPosRoster.early_departure.Value : empPosEarlyDeparture;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("d {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }

        var empLeaves = _lapp.GetAll(null, null, dt, dt, null, true, null, null, null, null);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("e {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        var att = GetAll(dt, new List<long> { emp.employee_id });
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("f {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        var obj = att.Count() > 0 ? att.First() : Get();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("g {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        var inRecords = _inOut.GetAll(obj.employee_attendance_id, true, null);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("h {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        var outRecords = _inOut.GetAll(obj.employee_attendance_id, null, true);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("i {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        obj.employee_id = emp.employee_id;
        obj.date = dt;
        obj.arrival_time = inRecords.Count() == 0 ? dt.TimeOfDay : obj.arrival_time;
        obj.departure_time = inRecords.Count() > 0 ? dt.TimeOfDay : obj.departure_time;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("j {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        dt.TimeOfDay - inRecords.First().@in.Value : obj.total_hours_worked;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("k {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        if (obj.arrival_time.HasValue && empPosLateArrival.HasValue && obj.arrival_time > empPosLateArrival)
        {
            obj.late_arrival = obj.arrival_time - empPosLateArrival;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("l {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        if (obj.early_departure.HasValue && empPosEarlyDeparture.HasValue && obj.departure_time < empPosEarlyDeparture)
        {
            obj.early_departure = empPosEarlyDeparture - obj.departure_time;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("m {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }

        obj.present = true;
        obj.leave = false;
        obj.holiday = false;
        obj.department_id = emp.department_id;
        obj.position_id = emp.position_id;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("n {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        var lapp = (
          from o in empLeaves
          where o.employee_id == emp.employee_id
          select o).FirstOrDefault();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("o {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        if (lapp != null && obj.present != true)
        {
            obj.leave = true;
            obj.leave_type_id = lapp.LeaveTypeId;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("p {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        var v = _inOut.Get();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("q {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        if (att.Count() > 0)
        {
            Update();
            v.attendance_id = obj.employee_attendance_id;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("r {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        else
        {
            Insert(obj);
            v.attendance_id = GetCurrentIdent();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("s {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        if (inRecords.Count() == 0)
        {
            v.@in = dt.TimeOfDay;
            v.inout_type_id = 1;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("t {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        else
        {
            v.@out = dt.TimeOfDay;
            v.inout_type_id = 2;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("u {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);
        }
        _inOut.Insert(v);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("v {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedTicks);

        return false;
    }
```